# How do I make an image into a link, that links to another image, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what I got so far, and I can't seem to get it to work..

It's the image that has the `id="hap_text"` that I want to be displayed when you click on the other image.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.touch_bg #touch_hap').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#hap_text').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
</script>

<div class="container touch_bg">
    <div>
        <a href="#"><img id="touch_hap" src="img/info/lefttouch.png"></a>
        <img id="hap_text" class="hidden" src="img/info/habitattext.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css is:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/m9m5q04o/. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: by the way, you don't really need to specify that `#touch_hap` is a child here`'.touch_bg #touch_hap'`. It's an ID, which means there should only be **one** anyway.

Comment: You included jQuery, right?

Comment: yeah the console is saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 2):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Don't forget to include jQuery. Otherwise, your code looks fine.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

```js
$(function() {
  $('.touch_bg #touch_hap').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#hap_text').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container touch_bg">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <img id="touch_hap" src="img/info/lefttouch.png">
    </a>
    <img id="hap_text" class="hidden" src="img/info/habitattext.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO! Thank you kindly in advance for accepting the answer (clicking the the check mark). Cheers.